# pyaudio Library Installation Error How to fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

When installing pyaudio in the command prompt with:

```
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c823_6j8\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vkr4rksd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c823_6j8\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vkr4rksd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c823_6j8\pyaudio\
```

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Do you have it installed?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply grab the proper Wheel package for your current Python version from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
and then install it with `pip install <PyAudio‑0.2.11-...>.whl`. (remember to use full filename (e.g `pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to download or any Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. Just do the following, it will be an ultimate fix:
After you go to this link: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ select and download the PyAudio for your Python version.

I downloaded:

`PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Place the downloaded file into the Scrips folder. My folder structure is:

```
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts`
```

Then you need to install the downloaded script by using the command:

`python -m pip install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"`

Comment: Why do you place the wheel file in the Scripts folder? It shouldn't be there. Almost any user directory (e.g. downloads folder) is fine, as long as you specify the correct path in the python command.

Comment: Actually this answer does not seem to add any new information that was not already mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55964261/10669875) by M.R.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that any directory is fine. I consider that as putting complete information @wovano